# Uploading an image(blob type)-Asp.Net-C#-Oracle 11g ex

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, oracle11g

I have been trying to perform a simple upload operation of an image using the asp FileUpload control and save it in Oracle database. Though I have hardcoded a few lines, I somehow succeeded. But then, I really want to understand the issue and I seek experts opinion. After a lot of googling, I attempted using various code snippets in my web application and eventually failed. Here is the code that partially worked for me.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strFileName = Path.GetFileName(imgUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
        String strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(imgUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        if (imgUpload.PostedFile != null)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                byteArray = new byte[fs.Length];
                int iBytesRead = fs.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            }
            string sql = " INSERT INTO IMAGETBL(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(:ID, :IMAGE) ";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVER_NAME=XE)));User Id=sakthi_studdb;Password=sakthi;");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, 4, ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("IMAGE", OracleDbType.Blob, byteArray, ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                secondlabel.Text = "Image added to blob field";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                secondlabel.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I run this code, it prompts Filenotfound error. Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0'
Then to make it work I had to manually copy paste my image file in the above mentioned location. There must be a way to create a directory and save the images there temporarily. Later the same image should be inserted in Oracle database.

```
                    HttpPostedFile imgFile = imgUpload.PostedFile;
            int imgFileLength = imgFile.ContentLength;
            if (imgFileLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgFile.FileName);
                var fileUpload = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/user_uploads"), fileName);
                imgFile.SaveAs(fileUpload);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileUpload))
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileUpload))
                    {
                        var input = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        var lines = Regex.Split(input, "#!#");
```

And another one..

`string path = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/user_uploads");
                    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                    imgUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fn));

                    Mylabel.Text = Path.GetFullPath(strFileName);
                    imgUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(strFileName);`

I hardly understood these snippets. Also, if you know easier methods to accomplish the same do suggest.  Kindly help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just uploading a file and want to push it to the Db you should be able to just grab the postedFile value and use it.

Tweaking your first snipped:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (imgUpload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(imgUpload.InputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = b.ReadBytes(imgUpload.ContentLength);

        string sql = " INSERT INTO IMAGETBL(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(:ID, :IMAGE) ";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVER_NAME=XE)));User Id=sakthi_studdb;Password=sakthi;");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, 4, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("IMAGE", OracleDbType.Blob, byteArray, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            secondlabel.Text = "Image added to blob field";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            secondlabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```